# How to use intel parallel studio and openmpi at the same time?

Tags: mpi, intel

In ubuntu, the default mpirun is openmpi as showed by

```
mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.10.2
```

But after install intel parallel studio and add following lines to `~/.bashrc`

```
. /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.4.056/psxevars.sh intel64
```

The mpirun becomes

```
mpirun --version
Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2017 Update 3 Build 20170405 (id: 17193)
Copyright (C) 2003-2017, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

But what if I want to use intel ifort but with openmpi? How to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume the default MPI on ubuntu is Open MPI compiled with GNU compilers.
there is no binary compatibility between GNU and Intel *Fortran* compilers, so you have to rebuild Open MPI with `ifort`
and then you have to prepend the install path to your `$PATH` and probably `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too.

Comment: Hi, @Gilles Gouaillardet. Thank you so much for answer. I tried your method. Build openmpi with intel, then add path and ld_library_path to bashrc, but `mpirun --version` still shows intel

Comment: what does 'which mpirun' says ?
you need to *prepend* the new location into your environment, export the variable ('export' or 'setenv') and you might also have to 'rehash'

Comment: Oh, you're right. I set the wrong path. Now it works. But there is a new problem. I have to link scalapack, so I add `-lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64`  according to link advisor. But I got bunches of `ompi_mpi_xxxx` undefined reference, what is wrong?

Comment: make sure the mkl libs are *before* the mpi libs.
i assume you use mpif90 or mpifort in order to link your app, so you can 'mpifort --showme ...' to get the full command line.
it should be something like "-lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64 -lmpi"